# Is the socket number return by accept(2) always greater than or equal to the first one in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to use the first file descriptor returned by accept(2) as the base number to define an array of size 65536-FD, with each element holding a TCP socket state.

I am writing a TCP service in hope of finding the minimum socket number returned by accept(2). So far I think it should be the first one, but I am not quite sure. If it is the truth, I can use socket numbers as indexes to access all socket states, or scan arrays to efficiently process all sockets (one producer one consumer lock-free approach).

Comment: No. It is indeterminate. If a lower FD gets released it may get reused for an accepted socket, and there is certainly no guarantee that all accepted socket FDs are sequential. And there is nothing that restricts the number of accepted socket FDs to 65536 either. What you need is a map indexed by socket number, rather than hoping for magical behaviour from the operating system.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, there is no 65536 restriction on FD number. But the socket map array has a upper boundary. Maybe 2-3 dimension array will be used as the socket map data structure. In this question, I just want to know if the FD returned by the first call of accept(2) is the minimum one compared to all sequential accept(2) returns per the Linux kernel implements.

Comment: Unless you're using 30 year old software, an array has a size limit of 2^31-1. But there is no reason to use arrays here.

Comment: Why not base the array at 0 since the lowest fd returned by accept(2) will probably be small anyway?